# How to merge two tables in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have two tables in one database
customer table have customer coordinate infos
Customer type have infos about the type of customer

I want to have a destination table that has

```
destination customer table
key
name
adress
...
type
```

I did create a database vue of customer table + customer type but the result query only showed me the fields that have customer table key=customer table foreign key in customer type

and there are also fields in customer table that have no type.
How do I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

What kind of transformations did you use in your data flow task?

I rather do it on the SQL Server using INNER JOIN and something like SELECT INTO. If you want to join two tables on SSIS, use the [Merge Join Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141775.aspx). However, the input for the Merge Join Transformation must be sorted so you can either use the Sort Transformation or just use ORDER BY when you get the data using OLE DB Source adaptors.

Hope this helps.